# Row chart puts zero at center when no data

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am creating row chart using dc.js in angular, but the chart is not aligned properly. See the screenshot below:

[image]

```
    var chartData=dc.rowChart(".div");
    
    chartData
        .width(900)
        .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]))
        .elasticX(true)
        .colorAccessor(d => d.key)
        .ordinalColors(this.mainColor)
        .dimension(countryDimension)
        .group(remove_empty_bins(countryGroup))
        .margins({ top: 10, right: 120, bottom: 70, left: 30 })
        .transitionDuration(500) 
        .renderLabel(true)
        .label(function (d) {
          return dc.utils.printSingleValue(d.x0 + d.x);
        })
       
        .renderlet(function (chart) {
          chart.selectAll("g.x text")
            .attr('font-size', '14px')
            .attr('dy', '0px')
            .attr('dx', '5px')
            .attr('font-weight', '100px')
            //.attr('transform', "rotate(35)")
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .attr("text", "Data")
        })
        .renderlet(function (chart) {
          chart.selectAll("g.x text")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (650 / 2) + " ," +
              (900 + 20 + 20) + ")")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Data1");
        })


        .renderlet(function (chart) {
          chart.selectAll("g.chart-body text").attr('dy', '15px')
            .attr('dx', '0px')
            .attr('z-index', '3')
            .attr('font-size', '16px')
            .attr('font-weight', '100px')
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .text("Data")
        })
        .label(p => {      
          return p.key
        })



        .keyAccessor(function (d) { 
          return d.value['name'];
        });

     
      var ValueAccessor = chartData.valueAccessor(function (d) {
        var count = 0;
        var count1 = 0;

        if (d.value['count'] > maxValue) {
          maxValue = d.value['count'];
        }
        if (maxValue > 1) {
          chartData.xAxis().ticks(4).tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
        }
        else {
          chartData.xAxis().ticks(1).tickFormat(d3.format("d"));
        }
        return d.value['count'];
      });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. When posting a bug report anywhere (not just here), it is very important to describe the expected behavior. What may look "improper" to you may be correct for someone else. Please edit your question to add this info.

Comment: I guess you are running into the case, when there is no data, D3 will display the axis from -1 to 1 instead of the expected 0 to 1. This is something that changed in version 6 of D3 and it has been previously reported (but I can't find the link atm). I think you would have to add a handler that sets the X axis domain when there is no data, to override the D3 default.

Comment: Thanks for hint Gordon. I will try and get back to yo.

Comment: Ok I found [the previous issue, with workaround](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1656). It affects the Y axis as well.

Comment: if i set chart.elasticX(false).y(d3.scaleLinear().domain([min, min+1])); then Y axis is shift to left side but x axis line is disabed. and if i set elasticX(true) then Y axis line is disaled but its show x axis line

Comment: Sounds like `min` may be NaN? I dunno, dc.js charts work best when there is data, may not look perfect when there is none.

Comment: we have removed all null beens, and if value is less then 0 then it will return 0.